# Capturing group recursively inside non-capturing group?

Tags: .net, regex

So I've got the following input: `1,6-10,10000,2,10-11`

And the following regex: `^\d+(?:,(\d+|\d+-\d+))*$` in the .NET Regex

I want to match each of the groups between the commas but I also want the capturing groups to end up like the following:

```
Group 1: 1
Group 2: 6-10
Group 3: 10000
Group 4: 2
Group 5: 10-11
```

I've tried using any combination of non-capturing groups and additional capturing groups that I could think of but I can't quite arrive at a solution. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered splitting the string on `,`?

Comment: I was trying to look into doing it with the regex only. I can easily achieve what I want with splitting afterwards, but I thought it would be an interesting exercise for myself with Regex. One that I wasn't able to solve however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .net regex implementation gives the possibility to store the substrings of a repeated capture group. So with this pattern that describes the whole string:

```
\A(?:(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,|\z))+\z
```

*(where `\A` and `\z` stand for the start and the end of the string)* you obtain all the values in capture group 1 with only one match: [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CA(%3F%3A(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A-%5Cd%2B)%3F)(%3F%3A%2C%7C%5Cz))%2B%5Cz&i=1%2C6-10%2C10000%2C2%2C10-11)

This way ensures that the whole string is in the correct format from the beginning to the end.

code example:

```
string input = "1,6-10,10000,2,10-11";
string pattern = @"\A(?:(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,|\z))+\z";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", match.Value);
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr < match.Groups.Count; ctr++) {
        Console.WriteLine(" Group {0}:  {1}", ctr, match.Groups[ctr].Value);
        int captureCtr = 0;
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[ctr].Captures) {
             Console.WriteLine("   Capture {0}: {1}", captureCtr, capture.Value);
             captureCtr++; 
        }
    }
}
```

An other way consists to use a global research (several successive matchs) and to ensure that all the results are contiguous. To do that you need to build a pattern with the `\G` anchor that matches the start of the string of the position after the previous match: [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CG(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A-%5Cd%2B)%3F)(%3F%3A(%2C)%7C%5Cz)&i=1%2C6-10%2C10000%2C2%2C10-11)

```
\G(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:(,)|\z)
```

To ensure that the end of the string has been reached, all you need is to check if the second capture group is empty for the last match.

code example:

```
string input = "1,6-10,10000,2,10-11";

string pattern = @"\G(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:(,)|\z)";

MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

if (results.Count == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("No results");
} else if ( results[results.Count - 1].Groups[2].Length > 0 ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Bad format");
} else {
    foreach (Match match in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you already know that your string is well formatted, these two approaches are useless, and a simple split on comma suffices to obtain the result.

Comment: So is the idea here that you run this with the .Matches method and then it will repeat the regex resulting in the desired result or what exactly do these \A and \z refer to when you say 'start' and 'end' of the string? How do they end up referring to the positions between the commas?

Comment: @Capsup: The first pattern describes a whole string that contains repeated numbers or ranges followed by a comma or the end of the string `(?:,|\z)`. In most of regex implementations, when a capture group is repeated, the next capture overwrites the previous and so one. But in .net, all previous captures are stored, and you can retrieve them. (See the code example)

Comment: Ah, so if I understand correct \A and \Z are equivalent to $ and ^ but does not accept line breaks? And because C# doesn't overwrite previous caught capture groups, it's possible to just get them assuming the regex successfully matched?

But why is it that the digits after the hyphen are actually in the capture when the part matching those are inside a non-capturing group?

Comment: @Capsup: take care of the case. `\A` and `\z` are equivalent to `^` and `$` most of the time. The only difference is that the meaning of `\A` and `\z` do not change with the multiline mode. So I prefer using them to be more explicit (and to avoid bad surprise).

Comment: @Capsup: `( \d+ (?:-\d+)? )` the fact the `-\d+` is in a non-capturing group doesn't change anything since the whole subpattern is enclosed in a capture group. The only difference with `( \d+ (-\d+)? )` is that a capture group 2 will be created for only `-\d+`. A non-capturing group doesn't exclude anything inside a capture group. It only groups things without creating a new capture.

Comment: Good to know, I actually thought the non-capturing groups would make everything inside them not be captured, but it actually makes more sense what you're saying. Thank you.